# Embedding previous and next button onto image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to embed a previous and next button onto the image such that both buttons resize and stay on the image when resized. But the problem is the buttons don't stay on the image and resize in a way that isn't consistent with what I want. I also want my image to be on the right side of the screen and text on the left side instead of on the center.

[image: buttons when the window is fullscreen]

[image: buttons after resizing the window to ~45%]

I thought if I had put the button in a div that is the child of the div my photos were in, the buttons would automatically be embedded onto the photo but that didn't work. I also set my parent container to relative and child container to absolute thinking that would work.

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}

.mySlides {
  display: none
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.photos {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  color: aqua;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  position: absolute;
  color: aqua;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.btn-responsive {
  /* matches 'btn-md' */
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

@media (max-width:760px) {
  /* matches 'btn-xs' */
  .btn-responsive {
    padding: 1px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="photos">
      <img class="mySlides fade" src="photos/quote1.jpg" style="width:95.7%" />
      <img class="mySlides fade" src="photos/quote2.jpg" style="width:95.7%" />
      <img class="mySlides fade" src="photos/quote3.jpg" style="width:95.7%" />
      <img class="mySlides fade" src="photos/quote4.jpg" style="width:95.7%" />
      <img class="mySlides fade" src="photos/quote5.jpg" style="width:95.7%" />
      <img class="mySlides fade" src="photos/quote6.jpg" style="width:95.7%" />
      <img class="mySlides fade" src="photos/photo8.png" style="width:95.7%" />


      <div class="img-overlay btn-responsive">
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is my first question, so if there are any improvements that are recommended when asking a question please let me know.

Comment: This is because your images are not taking the entire width of its parent div -- `.photos`. From your HTML, you can see that all slide images are set to a width of `width:95.7%`. So your prev and next buttons are positioned correctly in the `.photos` div, just the images aren't taking full width from their parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `<img>`s to expand edge to edge of it's container `.photos` and keep aspect ratio as well by changing `img` ruleset:

```css
img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also, remove `margin-top: -200px` from `.next, .prev`

I didn't see any text in OP code and didn't quite understand exactly what you wanted with text.

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slides");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}

.slides {
  display: none
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
}

.photos {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  color: aqua;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  user-select: none;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.btn-responsive {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

@media (max-width:760px) {
  .btn-responsive {
    padding: 1px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="photos">
      <img class="slides fade" src="https://www.pcgamesn.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/v-rising-castle-heart-decay-900x506.jpg" />
      <img class="slides fade" src="https://www.pcgamesn.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/jurassic-world-evolution-2-dominion-dlc-900x506.jpg" />
      <img class="slides fade" src="https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/clans//41627993/0bc70a88bed9dad1ba5898beb33c72476c2ccc10.jpg" />
      <img class="slides fade" src="https://www.pcgamesn.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/lost-ark-character-creation-900x506.jpg" />
      <img class="slides fade" src="https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/clans//9164327/b4569cd9085bd5d186c30877bc1251f03fc6e06a.jpg" />
      <div class="img-overlay btn-responsive">
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

iceiscold! Welcome to Stack Overflow.

I don't know if you have a specific reason for your widths, but setting the images to 100% width and set `object-fit: contain` should solve your resizing issues. If you need them smaller, you can control that by setting the photo container size, or creating a custom container for the `<img>`.

As for the layout question, to have a text and an image side by side, I recommend you to use `display: flex`. [Flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) is a nice CSS property for handling layouts. Another option would be to use `display: grid`, which is another way to handle layouts (see [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/grid)). For your case, I think flex is a bit more straightforward.

Basically what you need:

```
.parent{
    display: flex;
}

.child1, child2{
    flex: 1;
}
```

`.parent` will create a column layout, and with `flex:1` you are telling the flex property that both child1 and child2 should have the same width. You can play with that by setting `flex: 0.25`, etc. I used this on your code to create a description column and a photo column.

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.center {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.descriptions {
  flex: .75;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.photos {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.prev,
.next {
cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  color: aqua;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="descriptions">
    <p>I am a test description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="photos">
    <img class="mySlides fade" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1498641868397191170/6qW2XkuI_400x400.png" />
    <img class="mySlides fade" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/95/Test_image.jpg" />
    <img class="mySlides fade" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1498641868397191170/6qW2XkuI_400x400.png" />
    <div>
      <a class="prev" onClick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
      <a class="next" onClick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
Return to post
```